# Why is C printing this twice?

Tags: c

I'm sure this is simple, but can someone please tell me why the following code prints the user prompt twice? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    char task = 't';
    while (task != 'q') {
        printf("What do you want to do? (quit with 'q'): ");
        scanf("%c", &task);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
What do you want to do? (quit with 'q'): a
What do you want to do? (quit with 'q'): What do you want to do? (quit with 'q'): b
What do you want to do? (quit with 'q'): What do you want to do? (quit with 'q'): c
What do you want to do? (quit with 'q'): What do you want to do? (quit with 'q'): q
```

It exits on 'q' like it should. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It reads the character first and then - the newline you add by hitting `Enter`.

Comment: Thanks. The links to the duplicates answered my question perfectly.